# Custom markers for google places

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I am using the code below to display custom markers on my page using the google places.

```
var iconUrl;
   if(place.types[0] == 'lodging'){ iconUrl = 'custom-markers/hotel_marker.png'; }

   else
{
  iconUrl = place.icon;
}
```

How can i change the code above so i can display custom markers from more than one category?

For example:

```
if(place.types[0] == 'bars'){ iconUrl = 'custom-markers/bar_marker.png'; }
```

Comment: else if? or perhaps an associative array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
var iconUrl;
if(place.types[0] == 'lodging'){ iconUrl = 'custom-markers/hotel_marker.png'; }
else if(place.types[0] == 'bars'){ iconUrl = 'custom-markers/bar_marker.png'; }
else {
    iconUrl = place.icon;
}
```

The associative array approach would be something like:

```
var placeUrlLookup = { lodging: 'custom-markers/hotel_marker.png', bars: 'custom-markers/bar_marker.png' };
var iconUrl = place.icon; //set default here
if (place.types[0] in placeUrlLookup) {
    iconUrl = placeUrlLookup[place.types[0]];
}
```